# Converting tree list to hierarchy dict

Tags: python, tree, hierarchical-trees

I have a list of elements with attrs:  parent, level, is_leaf_node, is_root_node, is_child_node.

I want to convert this list to hierarchy dict.
Example of output dict:

```
{
        'Technology':
            {
             'Gadgets':{},
             'Gaming':{},
             'Programming':
                {
                    'Python':{},
                    'PHP':{},
                    'Ruby':{},
                    'C++':{}
                },
             'Enterprise':{},
             'Mac':{},
             'Mobile':{},
             'Seo':{},
             'Ui':{},
             'Virtual Worlds':{},
             'Windows':{},
            },
        'News':{
            'Blogging':{},
            'Economics':{},
            'Journalism':{},
            'Politics':{},
            'News':{}
            },}
```

I don't know algorithm. How to do it?

Comment: Is elem.parent a reference to a parent element? Or is it a string? That will be the difference between building this dict easily or not.

Comment: I have 2 parrent attrs. First is a "parent" which inclue string with parrent name and second is a "parent_id" which include INT id of parent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a less sophisticated, recursive version like chmod 700 described. Completely untested of course:

```
def build_tree(nodes):
    # create empty tree to fill
    tree = {}

    # fill in tree starting with roots (those with no parent)
    build_tree_recursive(tree, None, nodes)

    return tree

def build_tree_recursive(tree, parent, nodes):
    # find children
    children  = [n for n in nodes if n.parent == parent]

    # build a subtree for each child
    for child in children:
        # start new subtree
        tree[child.name] = {}

        # call recursively to build a subtree for current node
        build_tree_recursive(tree[child.name], child, nodes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything without a parent is your top level, so make those dicts first. Then do a second pass through your array to find everything with a parent at that top level, etc... It could be written as a loop or a recursive function. You really don't need any of the provided info besides "parent".

Comment: In first step, I do this:
In [121]: for x in cats:
    if x.parent:
        if not out.has_key(x.parent):
            out[x.parent]={}                    
        out[x.parent][x]={}
I have a trouble with recursion. How realize it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're basically wanting to do is a variant of [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  The most common algorithm for this is the source removal algorithm.  The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
import copy
def TopSort(elems): #elems is an unsorted list of elements.
    unsorted = set(elems)
    output_dict = {}
    for item in elems:
        if item.is_root():
            output_dict[item.name] = {}
            unsorted.remove(item)
            FindChildren(unsorted, item.name, output_dict[item.name])
    return output_dict

def FindChildren(unsorted, name, curr_dict):
    for item in unsorted:
        if item.parent == name:
            curr_dict[item.name] = {}
            #NOTE:  the next line won't work in Python.  You
            #can't modify a set while iterating over it.
            unsorted.remove(item)
            FindChildren(unsorted, item.name, curr_dict[item.name])
```

This obviously is broken in a couple of places (at least as actual Python code).  However, *hopefully* that will give you an idea of how the algorithm will work.  Note that this will fail horribly if there's a cycle in the items you have (say item a has item b as a parent while item b has item a as a parent).  But then that would probably be impossible to represent in the format you're wanting to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this might work:

```
def build_tree(category_data):
  top_level_map = {}
  cat_map = {}
  for cat_name, parent, depth in cat_data:
    cat_map.setdefault(parent, {})
    cat_map.setdefault(cat_name, {})
    cat_map[parent][cat_name] = cat_map[cat_name]
    if depth == 0:
      top_level_map[cat_name] = cat_map[cat_name]

  return top_level_map
```

Answer (score 0):

a nice recursive way to do it:

```
def build_tree(elems):
  elem_with_children = {}

  def _build_children_sub_tree(parent):
      cur_dict = {
          'id': parent,
          # put whatever attributes here
      }  
      if parent in elem_with_children.keys():
          cur_dict["children"] = [_build_children_sub_tree(cid) for cid in elem_with_children[parent]]
      return cur_dict

  for item in elems:
      cid = item['id']
      pid = item['parent']
      elem_with_children.setdefault(pid, []).append(cid)

  res = _build_children_sub_tree(-1) # -1 is your root
  return res
```